# Extract files from a ZIP archive with password

Tags: jscript

I'm working upon a script in JScript which shall extract filez from a ZIP archive which has a password. Firstly, I've found here on StackOverflow, on another thread a script in VBS which kinda resolved the problem, here it is :

```
WScript.echo("Instantiating a ZipFile object...")

Dim zip 
Set zip = CreateObject("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile")

WScript.echo("Initialize (Read)...")
zip.Initialize("C:\Temp\ZipFile-created-from-VBScript.zip")

WScript.echo("setting the password for extraction...")
zip.Password = "This is the Password."

' set the default action for extracting an existing file
' 0 = throw exception
' 1 = overwrite silently
' 2 = don't overwrite (silently)
' 3 = invoke the ExtractProgress event

zip.ExtractExistingFile = 1

WScript.echo("extracting all files...")
Call zip.ExtractAll("extract")

WScript.echo("Disposing...")
zip.Dispose()

WScript.echo("Done.")
```

I tried to rewrite this scipt in JScript, but when I was executing it, it was constantly returning an error related to `Ionic.Zip.ZipFile` library, and so I've come with another solution, now in JScript :

```
objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(zipFile).Items();
objShell.NameSpace(path).copyHere(FilesInZip, 4);
```

But, this script just extracts the files from an archive, Could somebody look over this code and help me, or, maybe purpose another solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won'tbe able to extract files from an archive with password using the last example, I'd recommend you using 7zip, or something similar instead. Here's an exemple of how will look the unarchive process with 7zip :

```
function ExtractFile(FileName, Password) {
    executableCommand = "x " + FileName + " -p" + Password;
    objShell.ShellExecute("7z.exe", executableCommand, /*Path to 7Zip*/, "open", 0);
}
```